# how to collect disallowed domain in colly

Tags: go

I'm a beginner in using the go language and I'm trying to build a crawler using it, but I'm facing two problems

1- I use colly.AllowedDomains to specify the scope for crawling, but I want the crawler to save domains outside the scope in garbage, but I have not found any way to do that

2 - I want when the crawl starts instead of printing the process like this
68 req/sec 903 endpoint(s) 1 depth 8s time passed
68 req/sec 903 endpoint(s) 1 depth 8s time passed
69 req/sec 904 endpoint(s) 1 depth 8s time passed
69 req/sec 925 endpoint(s) 1 depth 8s time passed
... Frequently
I want it to be a single line and have a overwrite
sorry for my english
code :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)


func main() {
    startURL := "https://example.com"    // Starting URL
    maxDepth := 1                         // Maximum depth to crawl
    maxThreads := 100                    // Maximum number of threads to use

    var wg sync.WaitGroup            // WaitGroup to synchronize threads
    var mu sync.Mutex                // Mutex to synchronize access to visited map

    visited := make(map[string]bool) // Keep track of visited URLs
    var endpointList []string
    var garbage []string
    // Create a new Collector with a limit on the maximum number of threads
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        //colly.Async(true),
        colly.AllowedDomains("example.com", "*.example.com"),
        colly.MaxDepth(maxDepth),
        colly.UserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"),
    )

    c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{DomainGlob: "*", Parallelism: maxThreads})

    // Set a random delay between requests to make them look more like human behavior
    c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{
        RandomDelay: 5 * time.Second,
    })

    // Create a log file to save errors
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("log.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer logFile.Close()

    // Use the log file to log errors
    logger := log.New(logFile, "error: ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    // On every visited page, execute this callback
    c.OnHTML("[href]", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        link := e.Attr("href")
        if strings.HasPrefix(link, "#") || 
            strings.HasPrefix(link, "tel") || 
            strings.HasPrefix(link, "mailto") || 
            strings.HasPrefix(link, "data:image") || 
            strings.HasPrefix(link, "javascript:") || 
            link == "" {
                // the link does not meet the conditions, so skip it
                return
        }
        
        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()
        if !visited[link] {
            visited[link] = true
            endpointList = append(endpointList, link)
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                linkURL := e.Request.AbsoluteURL(link)
                if linkURL != "" {
                    // Declare err here
                    err := c.Visit(linkURL)
                    if err != nil {
                        // Log the error to the log file
                        logger.Printf("%s (%s)>> %v\n", linkURL, link, err)
                    }
                }
            }()
        }else if !strings.HasPrefix(link, "http") {
            // convert relative URL to absolute URL
            linkURL := e.Request.AbsoluteURL(link)
            if linkURL != "" && !visited[linkURL] {
                visited[linkURL] = true
                endpointList = append(endpointList, linkURL)
                wg.Add(1)
                go func() {
                    defer wg.Done()
                    err := c.Visit(linkURL)
                    if err != nil {
                        logger.Printf("%s (%s)>> %v\n", linkURL, link, err)
                    }
                }()
            }
        }
    })
    c.OnHTML("[src]", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
            // Get the "src" attribute value
        jsURL := e.Attr("src")
        mu.Lock() // Lock the map
        defer mu.Unlock() // Unlock the map when done
        if !visited[jsURL] {
            visited[jsURL] = true
            endpointList = append(endpointList, jsURL)
        }
    })
    // On every request, execute this callback
    var reqCount int
    var st time.Time

    // On every request...
    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        // Increment the request count
        reqCount++

        // Get the start time if it's the first request
        if reqCount == 1 {
            st = time.Now()
        }

        // Print out the crawling statistics
        if int(time.Since(st).Seconds()) != 0 {
            fmt.Printf("\r%d req/sec  %d endpoint(s) %d depth %v time passed\n", reqCount/int(time.Since(st).Seconds()), len(endpointList), r.Depth, time.Since(st).Truncate(time.Second))
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("\r%d req/sec  %d endpoint(s) %d depth %v time passed\n", reqCount, len(endpointList), r.Depth, time.Since(st).Truncate(time.Second))
        }
    })

    // Start crawling from the initial URL
    visited[startURL] = true
    startTime := time.Now()
    c.Visit(startURL)

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    wg.Wait()

    // Display the number of links collected and the number of requests made
    fmt.Printf("\n\nCollected %d unique links\n", len(visited))

    // Display the number of requests per second (RPS)
    duration := time.Since(startTime)
    rps := float64(len(visited)) / duration.Seconds()
    fmt.Printf("Crawled at %.2f requests per second\n", rps)

    // Print all the endpoints found
    fmt.Printf("\nEndpoints found:\n")
    fmt.Printf("\ngarbage found:\n")
    results := struct {
        Endpoints []string `json:"endpoints"`
        Garbage   []string `json:"garbage"`
    }{
        Endpoints: endpointList,
        Garbage:   garbage,
    }

    file, err := os.Create("results.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    encoder := json.NewEncoder(file)
    encoder.SetIndent("", "    ")
    err = encoder.Encode(results)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

i tried to add this

```
        if !c.AllowedDomains[e.Request.URL.Hostname] {
        // the link's domain is not allowed, so add it to garbage
        garbeg = append(garbeg, link)
        return
        }
```

to c.OnHTML and doesn't work